# Preventing onclick moving items slightly and resetting them again to original position

Tags: jquery

I need a little advice regarding my problem with my vertical menu.

My problem is now that when I click a Button my other Buttons are moved a pixel down and then straight back up again. Just looks rooten. For example click on "Michael", "Jones", "Kuwait" our "Superman". You will see a small shift towards the bottom of the screen and then it resets itself to its original position.

```
var accordion_head = $('.accordion > li > a'),  
accordion_body = $('.accordion li > .sub-menu');
accordion_head.on('click', function (event) {
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active') {
        accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
        $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideToggle('normal');
        accordion_head.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

You can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RTcf3/

How can this be fixed? Help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot and have a great weekend

TD.

Comment: This is because the UL that is a child of the li that is being clicked on is becoming visible, causing a small shift in the DOM.

Comment: Of course, I didn't realize that the empty UL would cause this. Thanks Stefan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I would change your code a bit and make it check if the current menu actually has a submenu so it won't try to show a ul that is empty (in case you'll have some menus with submenus, and others without submenus). Let me know if you need help to do that.

Here's what I have on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Seventh/RTcf3/7/):

```
$('.accordion > li').on('click', function (evt) {
    var accordion_body = $('.sub-menu', this);
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {

    } else {
        $('.active .sub-menu').slideUp();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        if(accordion_body.is(':empty')){

        } else {
            accordion_body.slideDown('normal');
        }
    }   
});
```

I also did a small change on your CSS. You have an anchor link displaying: relative. It makes no sense at all since it will never have a child tag.

Comment: I'd love some help, at the end of the day I will though most likely fill all submenus with content. Even if I do, the minor shift still happens..

Comment: I just edited my answer. The code can be improved if you won't use those empty if statements...

Comment: Thanks a bunch. First problem solved. However, when I click between "Bert" and "Michael" the problem is still there. Any idea why?

Comment: This is strange. My guess is that when you click a menu, it will slide the current sub-menu Up (and hide it), and slide the clicked sub-menu Down (and show it), but during a fraction of time, both sub-menus are being shown and taking space. What you could do is set 2 different speeds for the menu, like so: slideUp('normal')... slideDown('slow'). Yes, the "problem" is still there but this way it will look like an effect. Optionally, you may wait for one slide to finish to start another one.

Comment: And to prove that, simply change the line inside the last 'else statement' to this: accordion_body.delay(400).slideDown(); We're simply adding a delay to the slideDown and it will wait for the slideUp effect to end before it slidesDown... You'll see that the menu is not "jumpy". So, to me it looks more like a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I will use the combination "slow" and "normal", it makes things look just fine.